# Cone and space homeomorphism question

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds, geometric-topology

I am wondering:

Under what conditions is a space homeomorphic to its cone?
Moreover, if $M$ is a compact manifold, is it always homeomorphic to its cone? What about if for manifolds of different dimensions? That is, does there exists a dimension where $M^n$ is homeomorphic to its cone?

Comment: Have you tried any examples at all?

Comment: I’m just curious, I just suddenly woke up and thought of this, so I didn’t have enough time. But thinking about this more, if we have the sphere, then it’s cone is homeomorphic to the closed disk.  But the sphere is not homeomorphic to the disk, other than that, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are certainly spaces where $CX \approx X$, but manifolds do never have this property.

Let $M$ be  manifold of dimension $n$. Then $CM$ contains an open subspace homeomorphic to $M \times (0,1)$ (simply remove the tip and the base $X \times \{0\}$ from $CX$). If $CM \approx M$, then $M$ would contain an open subspace homeomorphic to $M \times (0,1)$  i.e. a manifold of dimension $n+1$. This is impossible.

A positive example is the Hilbert cube $Q$  (the countable infinite product of closed unit intervals). We have $CQ \approx Q$; see [here](https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/700806/Toposym_03-1971-1_97.pdf).

Comment: A cheaper, but perhaps slightly simpler example of a space homeomorphic to its cone would also be an infinite simplex.